# Pulling a field from another table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables, which have a one-to-one relationship and look something like this:

**OrderItem**

```
ID    data1   data2   data3
1     a       b       c
2     d       e       f
3     g       h       i
```

**DisputedItem**

```
ID    data4
1     q
3     r
```

Is there a way to pull `data4` into my Hibernate model for OrderItem without having a separate DisputedItemModel? Preferably using annotations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Hibernate `@Formula` annotation, if you have annotation based mappings or `<formula>` tag if you are mapping by XML.

What formula can do is help you extract a value by a query and map it to a field in your OrderItem domain model. This field can be from any table but the query thats used to map the property should return the indented field type.

You can use following URL for reference [Hibernate Formula](http://gokhan.ozar.net/hibernate-derived-properties-formula-annotation/)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, here is an example:

```
@Table(name = "table")
public class c
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int Id;

    @Formula("(select t.data from table t where t.ID = ID))")
    private String data;
}
```

Comment: should there be 2 brackets after ID?

Comment: The thread starter asked for referencing a column of another table. However, your example is using the same table.